# Zend Framework: Why some errors are rendered with the ErrorController but some just shows inline

Tags: zend-framework

i wonder why some errors can be rendered in the error controller but some are just output inline like a normal php script would. most of the time, with 'inline' errors, the whole page is blank apart from the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to a number of factors, the most relevant probably are :

1. It's a fatal error : the PHP interpreter ALWAYS stops on fatal errors, if you have display_errors in php.ini set to on (or 1) then they will also be displayed in the browser.
2. You have some code with a `die` statement. Again, PHP will stop executing your script and echo whatever you gave as parameter to the `die` call.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the ErrorController picks up Exceptions, provided that the front controller is  configured to route them to the ErrorController. Otherwise, it's standard PHP error handling as specified by `display_errors` and any error handler registered with `set_error_handler()`.